# shift to or into sth

Tags: prepositions

I have the following sentence:

"Optimization approaches can shift the load **into** times with low prices in the electricity market"

Can I use 'into' here or do I have to use 'to'? I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Optimization approaches can shift the load into times with low prices in the electricity market"* is not particularly idiomatic - it is too verbose: *"Optimization can shift the load into periods with/of low electricity prices."*

**To** something ~ as far as the beginning of something - He went to London = He went as far as the point at which London began.

**Into** is used with motion to indicate a change of state: *"He walked into the room."* = "His state changed from being outside the room to being inside the room" thus there is implied motion.

"The wizard turned the prince into a frog" There is a change of state without motion - he was human and became a frog.

You need to indicate the change of state from expensive electricity to cheap electricity.

To shift is a verb of motion and "into" = to a point *within or inside* periods with/of low electricity prices.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard for your answer. To be totally honest, I can't really understand the logic you presentend. If I write: 'He moved from Manchester to London' his state has also changed. So I could also write :'He moved from Manchester into London' which is obviously wrong. But I understand that I should use 'into' in my examples

Comment: "I am hot" Describes the state of being hot. His state changes as he **was** in Manchester, but when he is in London, he is not *[in the state of being]* in Manchester. "State" has a wider interpretation to the one that you are imagining. ++ You could write "'He moved from a house in Manchester into a house in London' ++ "Do not worry too much about "state" - as I said, the prepositions are usually used with a verb of motion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greybeard.